# Как оптимизировать SELECT к двум таблицам?

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть таблица Модели и таблица Разделы

Таблица Модели (model)

```
id name cat
1 Corolla 2
2 Camry 2
3 VFR800 5
```

Таблица Разделы (cat)

```
id name sub_id
1 Авто 0
2 Седаны 1
3 Универсалы 1
4 Мотоциклы 0
5 Спортивные 4
```

В таблице Разделы, есть разделы с cat.sub_id=0 (Главные разделы) и cat.sub_id=cat.id (Подразделы Главного раздела)

Необходимо:

1. На странице Родительского раздела вывести все модели и название
   Родительского раздела.
2. На странице Подраздела вывести модели относящиеся к Подразделу и
   название Подраздела.

Решение: (id нам известно, оно может только одно, для главного раздела, или для подраздела)

Пример 1

```
select model.name, (select cat.name where cat.id=1) as catname
from model,cat
where model.cat in (select cat.id from cat where cat.id=1 or cat.sub_id=1)
and model.cat = cat.id
```

Выведет Авто и модели Corolla, Camry

Пример 2

```
select model.name, (select cat.name where cat.id=2) as catname
from model,cat
where model.cat in (select cat.id from cat where cat.id=2 or cat.sub_id=2)
and model.cat = cat.id
```

Выведет Седаны и модели Corolla, Camry

Эти запросы работают, но меня смущают подзапросы. Это хороший вариант или есть более красивое решение?

Comment: Мне вот страшно просто представить... А если Вы на сайте еще сделаете, например, менюшку, которая тоже в базе будет храниться. А потом еще личные сообщения пользователей. Вы всё это будете пытаться делать одним запросом?)

Comment: @Александр Белинский, спасибо за уточнение. У меня пока мало опыта в разработке, поэтому, видимо, делаю ошибки в проектировании. Я подумал, что если у меня участвуют две таблицы, то я просто обязан взять оттуда все данные, что мне нужны сразу. Вполне можно было сделать 2 отдельных запроса? Один для вывода моделей, второй для заголовка?

Comment: извиняюсь, сразу не понял всю глубину вопроса. То есть, Вы хотите одним запросом потрошить всё дерево, записанное в одну таблицу?.. Для этого, как я понимаю, лучше выбрать Postgre - фанаты говорят, что там есть рекурсивный join из коробки. Или же Вам очень-очень нужно именно в mysql это хранить? А вложенность у Вас ограничена?

Comment: @Александр Белинский, да, необходим mysql. Сейчас у меня 2 таблицы, это модели и разделы. Модели привязаны к разделам. Разделы имеют структуру Раздел - > подраздел - > еще подраздел. Пример, авто - > седаны - > ауди. Задача в том, чтобы при доступе к разделу выводить все записи, включая записи из подразделов. При доступе к подразделу выводить только записи из подраздела. Сложность была не с выводом записей, их можно через IN найти, а с выводом названия разделов. Здесь решение нашлось добавлением еще одного select, который и вызвал у меня сомнения в правильности решения.

Comment: А зачем именно потребовались подзапросы ? если в основном запросе написать `and (cat.id=1 or cat.sub_id=1)` разве он не даст то же самое ? про вторую колонку выборки то же ничего не ясно, таблиц в ней не используется. Вы таким образом вместо `if(cat.id=1,cat.name,NULL)` получаете имя только для записи с sub_id=1 ?

Comment: И до тех пор пока вам нужен только один-два уровня иерархии у вас нет вообще никаких проблем и не надо обращать внимание на комментарии выше. вот если вам действительно нужна рекурсия, что бы достать одним запросом скажем вообще все подразделы в глубину дерева, т.е. если бы была например еще запись с sub_id=2 и надо было то же ее доставать и еще глубже, если есть что то под ней, то запрос получается нетривиальный и об оптимизации вообще уже говорить не приходится

Comment: @Mike, да я уже понял, что зря написал это. Я просто испугался, что он хочет там неограниченную вложенность. Но потом пригляделся к запросам, и похоже что действительно не всё так страшно и там всего 1 вложенность категорий максимально.